# How to substitute number of words simultaneously using Stream Editor?

Tags: sed

**inputfile : multiple_sed.txt**

```
perl is an interpreterated language

it has three data types

scalar

array

hashes

scalar is a single value
```

I tried the below command:

```
sed -e 's/array/scalar/g;s/was/is/g' multiple_sed.txt
```

**Output:**

```
perl is an interpreterated language

it has three data types

scalar

scalar

hashes

scalar is a single value
```

I tried the above command for two words substitution but how can I  change the number of words substitution (i.e more than 100 words).

How I can do it with stream editor (sed)?

Comment: Would like to help but will appreciate if you can elaborate your question a little more on what you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a list of words with their substitution text :

**wordsfile:**

```
array scalar
is was
interpreterated interpreted
```

You can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
$ sed -f <(sed 's/^/s\//g;s/ /\//;s/$/\//g' wordsfile) multiple_sed.txt
perl was an interpreted language

it has three data types

scalar

scalar

hashes

scalar was a single value
```

With the inner `sed` command passed to `-f`, all lines in `wordsfile` are formatted to a sed substitution command. The result is send to the external sed that process the substitutions in `multiple_sed.txt`.

**Edit:**

As suggested by potong, using a different delimiter in the inner sed command make it more readable (also removed the `g` modifier that is useless here):

```
sed -f <(sed 's/^/s#/;s/ /#/;s/$/#/' wordsfile) multiple_sed.txt
```

Comment: As you are using the metacharacters `^` and `$` in the LHS of the substitution commands, there is no need for the `g` flag (it can only occur once). Perhaps using a different delimiter may also make the command clearer? i.e. `sed 's/^/s#/;s/ /#/;s/$/#/' wordsfile`